# read data from cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Please help.. cant help it. I did everything I can but couldn't solve this. the problem is mostly about ***docs*** in the ListView.Build's item count section. before it used to be documents not its ***docs*** and it doesn't work

[image]

```dart
class Toyota extends StatefulWidget {
  const Toyota({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Toyota> createState() => _ToyotaState();
}

class _ToyotaState extends State<Toyota> {
 // final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("toyota").get();

 final CollectionReference _toyota = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("toyota");
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text(
          "Toyota",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontFamily: "eng"),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: _toyota.snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['name']),
                  subtitle: Text(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index].data()['age']),
                );
              });
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
            
          })
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: please post the code here, and where is the list variable docs, please provide it.

Comment: @Mado here you go I updated the question and added the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: _toyota.snapshots(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
     if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
       return Center(
         child: Container(),
       );
     }
     return ListView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
           Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
           return Text(data['name']);
        }).toList(),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: it does not recognize the map in the children of ListView. this is the error (  The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'.  )